# Regex for Windows "Message" from syslog source

Tags: regex, windows, syslog

I have Windows logs being aggregated to a syslog server which is messing with the format a little bit and I'm trying to work a regular expression (PCRE) to be reformat it a little so I can extract some key/value pairs

I've had a go at the regular expression myself, but I'm stuck on the fact that each "Message" section has several "Headers" which have defined key/value pairs underneath them.

An example would be:
`An attempt was made to access an object. Subject: Security ID: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Account Name: NAME$ Account Domain: DOMAIN Logon ID: 0x3e7 Object: Object Server: Security Object Type: File Object Name: Z:\PATH\PATH\PATH\file.log Handle ID: 0x9b0 Process Information: Process ID: 0xa84 Process Name: C:\Program Files\PROGRAM\EXECUTABLE.exe Access Request Information: Accesses: ReadData (or ListDirectory) Access Mask: 0x1`

The headers would be Subject, Object and Process Information.

Where I seem to be stuck is the only delimiter here is \s regardless of a header or pair.

This has got me close.
`\s([^:\s]+)\:[\s]([^\s]*)` but only captures the first word in a multi-word header or key.

With /s being the only delimiter, will this be possible?

Comment: Perhaps you could configure syslog to "clean" the incoming message differently, eg by escaping `\n` (eg to hex) instead of deleting it? If you capture the raw tcp packet coming in from the network (with something like `sudo tcpdump -X -p  '(ip proto \tcp) and (src host 192.168.0.20)'`) does it still have `\r\n`? If not can the source machine be configured differently.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want those header names you might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and list the words between word boundaries `\b`.

Note that you don't have to escape the `:` and a single `\s` could also be written  without the square brackets.

```
\b(Process Information|\S+)\b:\s(\S*)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(` Capturing group 1

  - `Process Information|\S+` Match any of the listed
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\b:\s` Match word boundary, `:` and whitespace char
- `(\S*)` Capturing group 2 matching 0+ times a non whitespace char

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N5rloi/1)

Comment: hey! thanks for your answer, but I was hoping for the opposite :) where the key/value pairs are captured. The headers don't mean much in the bigger picture. The other part is that the headers (and even keys) aren't always the same (those were just from the above example) and there could be fewer or more than the example as well.

Comment: @skittles Is the data structured or is it a string like in the example? So you want to capture all the keys and values in this format: `string1 optionalstring: value optionalvalue`?

Comment: the data is exactly as above. syslog removes any structure like \n\r or \t that it may have had before :(
optional header: ```mandatory key: mandatory value mandatory key: mandatory value...```
The spaces are literal as they could be one or two words.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the difference between the header and a key?

Comment: systematically? I don't think so. Im not even sure if finding the ```:``` and working backwards until the previous ```:``` would be helpful here either

Comment: Is there any other pattern or structure to be detected in the data? No fixed set of headers or keys?